# is there a way in R to subtract two rows within a group by specifying another grouping var?

Tags: r

Say I have something like this:

```
ID = c("a","a","a","a","a", "b","b","b","b","b")
Group = c("1","2","3","4","5", "1","2","3","4","5")
Value = c(3, 4,2,4,3, 6, 1, 8, 9, 10)
df<-data.frame(ID,Group,Value)
```

I want to subtract group=5 from group=3 within the ID, with an output column which has this difference for each ID like so:

```
   ID Group Value Want
1   a     1     3    1
2   a     2     4    1
3   a     3     2    1
4   a     4     4    1
5   a     5     3    1
6   b     1     6    2
7   b     2     1    2
8   b     3     8    2
9   b     4     9    2
10  b     5    10    2
```

Also, if that calculation cannot be done (i.e. group 5 is missing), NA values for the 'want' column would be ideal.

Answer (score 4):

As there is only one unique 'Group' per 'ID', we can do subsetting

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
    mutate(want = Value[Group == 5] - Value[Group == 3])
# A tibble: 10 x 4
# Groups:   ID [2]
#   ID    Group Value  want
#   <fct> <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 a     1         3     1
# 2 a     2         4     1
# 3 a     3         2     1
# 4 a     4         4     1
# 5 a     5         3     1
# 6 b     1         6     2
# 7 b     2         1     2
# 8 b     3         8     2
# 9 b     4         9     2
#10 b     5        10     2
```

The above can be made more error-proof if we convert to numeric index and get the first element.  When there are no TRUE, by using `[1]`, it returns `NA`

```
df %>%
   slice(-10) %>%
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(want = Value[which(Group == 5)[1]] - Value[which(Group == 3)[1]])
```

---

Or use `match` which returns an index of `NA` if there are no matches, and anything with `NA` index returns `NA` which will subsequently return `NA` in subtraction (`NA -3`)

```
df %>% 
    slice(-10) %>% # removing the last row where Group is 10
    group_by(ID) %>%  
    mutate(want = Value[match(5, Group)] - Value[match(3, Group)])
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` method:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, want := (Value[Group == 5] - Value[Group == 3]), by = .(ID)]

df
#     ID Group Value want
#  1:  a     1     3    1
#  2:  a     2     4    1
#  3:  a     3     2    1
#  4:  a     4     4    1
#  5:  a     5     3    1
#  6:  b     1     6    2
#  7:  b     2     1    2
#  8:  b     3     8    2
#  9:  b     4     9    2
# 10:  b     5    10    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using base R.

```
unsplit(
    lapply(
        split(df, df$ID),
        function(d) {
            x5 = d$Value[d$Group == "5"]
            x5 = ifelse(length(x5) == 1, x5, NA)
            x3 = d$Value[d$Group == "3"]
            x3 = ifelse(length(x3) == 1, x3, NA)
            d$Want = x5 - x3
            d
        }),
    df$ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- Reduce(rbind,
                lapply(split(df,df$ID),
                       function(x) within(x, Want <-diff(subset(Value, Group %in% c("3","5"))))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
   ID Group Value Want
1   a     1     3    1
2   a     2     4    1
3   a     3     2    1
4   a     4     4    1
5   a     5     3    1
6   b     1     6    2
7   b     2     1    2
8   b     3     8    2
9   b     4     9    2
10  b     5    10    2
```