# Subtract two rows based on an index in R

Tags: r

I have the following database. My intention is to subtract the scores of each name according to the category and Index. That is **b - a** of every name according the index.

My database

```
dat <- read.table(text="
Name    Score   Index    Category
Pepe        5      Al           a
Pepe        1      Bl           b
Juan        8      Cl           a
Juan        5      Al           b
Mikel       1      Cl           a
Mikel       6      Bl           b
", header=TRUE)
```

I want obtain this:

[image]

Can you help me, please?

Comment: hi, might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59429876/is-there-a-way-in-r-to-subtract-two-rows-within-a-group-by-specifying-another-gr

Comment: not exactly what i want

Comment: Please post data in `dput` format not as images. Edit the question with the output of `dput(head(database))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways, base R and package `dplyr`.

## Base R

Use `aggregate` to compute the differences, then `merge` with the original data set to have the other columns in the result and `subset` by `Category`.
To keep the names order, the 2nd solution uses `order` to first get an index `i`.

```r
df1 <- data.frame(
  Name = c("Pepe", "Pepe", "Juan", "Juan", "Mikel", "Mikel"),
  Score = c(5,1,8,5,1,6),
  Index = rep(c("AI", "BI", "CI"), 2),
  Category = rep(c("a", "b"), 3)
)

merge(
  aggregate(Score ~ Name, df1, diff),
  subset(df1, select = -Score),
  by = "Name"
) |> subset(Category == "b")
#>    Name Score Index Category
#> 2  Juan    -3    AI        b
#> 4 Mikel     5    CI        b
#> 6  Pepe    -4    BI        b


i <- order(unique(df1$Name))
merge(
  aggregate(Score ~ Name, df1, diff),
  subset(df1, select = -Score),
  by = "Name"
) |> subset(Category == "b") |>
  (\(x) x[order(i), ])()
#>    Name Score Index Category
#> 6  Pepe    -4    BI        b
#> 2  Juan    -3    AI        b
#> 4 Mikel     5    CI        b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

## Package `dplyr`

The same algorithm as above but with `dplyr` functions.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(dplyr))

left_join(
  df1 %>% group_by(Name) %>% summarise(Score = diff(Score)),
  df1 %>% select(-Score),
  by = "Name"
) %>%
  filter(Category == "b")
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   Name  Score Index Category
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr> <chr>   
#> 1 Juan     -3 AI    b       
#> 2 Mikel     5 CI    b       
#> 3 Pepe     -4 BI    b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>